# Android WebView not showing data

Tags: java, android, webview

Hi I'm developing an android app which uses a webview. I had it working on froyo by using:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(urlString)) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
             handler.proceed();
        }
    });
```

For some reason this code just doesn't get hit when using froyo, a white screen is displayed. This was working fine a week ago and have come back to make some changes and it doesn't work now. the code just doesn't get hit when I add a breakpoint to it. can anyone suggest whats gone wrong? I can add all of the code if it will help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache data of the app? It does not seem to be anything strange in the given snippet... other changes in the code?

Comment: I'll do that now, I haven't changed any code that was working a week ago, I've made changes but nothing that would affect the webview

Comment: I've even reverted back to the code where It was working and it's still not working. does anyone know why it would have just stopped working?

Comment: So I've just been for my lunch and tested the app again without changing any of the code, and it's now working perfectly. do you know why it would just randomly stop working even though the web page was viewable in other android devices and desktop browsers

Comment: Have you checked the logcat for any strange log?

Comment: Yeah and can't see anything. What I've done is save the log so if it occurs again, I can check to see what's different. Also, I've just realised that it wasn't on Froyo, it was on Gingerbread 2.3.5 API, which I thought should just work ok shouldn't it?

Comment: you can add code for debugging to test how far it goes and when stops here are tips for WebView logging https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html